# jQuery DataTables fixedColumns remove fixed columns dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [fixedColumns](http://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) plugin for my [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/reference/) component. And I want to allow users to toggle fixed columns from the table header.

Creating the fixed columns is straign forward:

```
this.table.fixedColumns = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(this.table, {
    iLeftColumns: index + 1
});
```

I wonder, how can I change the fixedColumns created, or if I can't, that seems like the case, cause I tried updating `iLeftColumns` option and doing `fnUpdate` but had no effect:

```
this.table.fixedColumns.s.iLeftColumns = 0;
this.table.fixedColumns.fnUpdate();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was answered by dykstrad above to change the number of columns fixed you can use `iLeftColumns` setting, like this:

```
var fixedColumns = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(this.table, {
    iLeftColumns: 1
});
fixedColumns.s.iLeftColumns = 3;
fixedColumns.fnRedrawLayout();
```

However removing fixed columns is impossible with this method, for that you need to hide the overlay plugin produces or destroy the instance all together, I've decided to destroy it, so I've extended the plugin with this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns.prototype.destroy = function(){
    var nodes = ['body', 'footer', 'header'];

    //remove the cloned nodes
    for(var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++){
        if(this.dom.clone.left[nodes[i]]){
            this.dom.clone.left[nodes[i]].parentNode.removeChild(this.dom.clone.left[nodes[i]]);
        }
        if(this.dom.clone.right[nodes[i]]){
            this.dom.clone.right[nodes[i]].parentNode.removeChild(this.dom.clone.right[nodes[i]]);
        }
    }

    //remove event handlers
    $(this.s.dt.nTable).off( 'column-sizing.dt.DTFC destroy.dt.DTFC draw.dt.DTFC' );

    $(this.dom.scroller).off( 'scroll.DTFC mouseover.DTFC' );
    $(window).off( 'resize.DTFC' );

    $(this.dom.grid.left.liner).off( 'scroll.DTFC wheel.DTFC mouseover.DTFC' );
    $(this.dom.grid.left.wrapper).remove();

    $(this.dom.grid.right.liner).off( 'scroll.DTFC wheel.DTFC mouseover.DTFC' );
    $(this.dom.grid.right.wrapper).remove();

    $(this.dom.body).off('mousedown.FC mouseup.FC mouseover.FC click.FC');

    //remove DOM elements
    var $scroller = $(this.dom.scroller).parent();
    var $wrapper = $(this.dom.scroller).closest('.DTFC_ScrollWrapper');
    $scroller.insertBefore($wrapper);
    $wrapper.remove();

    //cleanup variables for GC
    delete this.s;
    delete this.dom;
};
```

With this method on board removing and reapplying is simple:

```
fixedColumns.destroy();
```

and then from the very beginning:

```
var fixedColumns = new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(this.table, {
    iLeftColumns: 3
});
```

Comment: How to fix this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436791/prevent-the-jquery-datatable-to-restore-to-initial-state-when-clicking-the-toggl?noredirect=1#comment41562339_26436791

Comment: For me once I use ```fixedColumns.destroy();``` I can't re-create them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need to do is to redraw the table after making the change:

`this.table.draw()`

Comment: fixedColumns.fnUpdate() does that, and it doesn't work. I had to code the destroy method to the plugin, will post my self-answer soon.

Comment: @Brock Did you ever find a working solution? I'm having a hard time going from 0 to 1 as well as 1 to 0 when dynamically updating the number of fixed columns

Comment: Refer to the answer I've posted

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I did the following:

1. Set leftColumns and iLeftColumns
2. call fnUpdate()
3. call fnRedrawLayout()

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT:
fnRedrawLayout() already calls fnUpdate() so...

1. Set leftColumns and iLeftColumns
2. Call fnRedrawLayout()

Comment: Yes, this is very close to what I've ended up with.

Comment: @Brock I am finding my solution isn't complete, what did you end up with? I am running into a problem going from 1 fixed column to 0 or 0 fixed columns to 1.

Comment: I've had to extend fixedColumns plugin with a 'destroy' method. In this method I'm deleting all clones plugin has created and switching off all event handlers it assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $(".your table class name")["1"]
var tableClone = $(".your table class name")["3"]
table.children["1"].children[currentRowId].remove();
tableClone.children["1"].children[currentRowId].remove();
```

I hope this will help you. It will not slow down the performance as it is directly trying to remove the rows from your table.