# Prevent the jquery datatable to restore to initial state when clicking the toggle button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, datatables

Here I have a bootstrap styled fixed [column datatable](http://jsfiddle.net/eqsadgez/15/) where i can toggle the columns by a button as,

```
 $('#ToggleColumns').click(function () { 
      table.destroy();
  if(columnNumber == 2)
  {
columnNumber = 0;  
  }
  else {
  columnNumber = 2; 
  }
  });
```

If I am at the 3rd page of datatable pagination and when I toggling the columns, the table restores to its initial position. ie, first page. How can I prevent it and be there in the 3rd page itself after toggling? The same applies to the no. of record selection too.

Comment: The [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) function might be what you need

Comment: Where/when should I add draw()?

Comment: Did you have a look at the link? You're using datatables 1.10 which I'm not really familiar with, but you should be.